# cronjob or similar to open a local php file including query

Tags: nginx, php, debian, cron

How do I open the following file with cronjob correctly every 5 minutes:

```
/var/www/mysite/folder/foo.php?query=1
```

I tried myself but I just did not get it working. I tried with `/usr/share/php5`, `wget`, nothing worked. I checked nginx access log if the file gets called but no it did not.

Yes **cron** service is running properly. And the priviliges on the `foo.php` are **755** (executable)

I tried calling the file by just typing:

```
/usr/share/php5 /var/www/mysite/folder/foo.php?query=1
```

But it just says:

```
/usr/share/php5: Is a directory
```

So what do I do wrong? What is there to do?

It's important that the php file is called including the query, as this itself is a cron process for wordpress. Just calling the `foo.php` doesn't help me.

I tried for 2 hours now but i'm giving up. Please help me out guys.

PS: using debian wheezy, php5 fpm, the usual.

Comment: If you use `http://example.com/foo.php?query=1` (where example.com is your website) what happens ?

Comment: you mean /usr/share/php5 example.com/folder/foo.php?query=1 instead of /usr/share/php5 /var/www/mysite/folder/foo.php?query=1 ? the same.

Comment: I mean what I said presuming that foo.php is in the document root otherwise substitute a suitable url.

Comment: Just so you know...it's `/usr/bin/php` *not* `/usr/share/php` for the actual executable.

Comment: hey man, i don't have /usr/bin/php according to what my linux tells me

Comment: Type `whereis php` to get the path of the executable. It'll list different folders, but in almost all distros i know of it's in a `bin` folder somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use PHP's $argv array that is available in CLI scripts.

Example cron:

`* * * * * * /var/www/mysite/folder/foo.php 1`

In your php file $argv variable will be available where $argv[1] (Second element) will be the supplied argument. So if you can modify this scrip to work with $argv, then this is a good solution.

If you HAVE to use a url parameters, then you must be requesting an actual page, so you would have to have something like this:

`* * * * * * curl http://localhost/mysite/folder/foo.php?query=1`

```
Assuming that http://localhost/ is located in /var/www/
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: it says "curl command not found"

Comment: It's possible you don't have curl installed.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the *share directory* for php and the *php binary*. The file you should use probably is `/usr/bin/php`.

The path for your script is probably wrong too, as @jin-pow told you. You may have to use `/var/www/whatever/foo.php`.

And if you run it passing `?query=1`, it will not work, as PHP will complain that he will not be able to find the script. And your script will not have a `$_GET['query']`variable. You will have to use the `$argv` array.

Wrapping up, your cron entry should be something like this:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/whatever/foo.php 1
```

And on your PHP script:

```
<?php
$query = $argv[1];
....

?>
```

Comment: i dont have /usr/bin/php says my linux

Comment: If you have *php5-cli* installed, it generally is there. You can use `which php` to get where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Owww man i just answered it myself.

wget was not working with url because it is an onion site, so it said host not found/reachable whatever.

wget was not working via /var/www/...... because it said Scheme missing.

Issue was resolved by using the server IP:Port instead of the URL. My cron job is working fine now.

Can somebody just tell me if it's ok to just have it with wget IP:PORT/etc or should i do wget -O /dev/null ?

Comment: dammit it doesn't work! in access log it shows up normally as a get request like when i open the URL in browser, but the actual php cron isn't properly runned as the things that should update on the site don't update. the .php is not the problem. wget is. how can i do it otherwise? it says i dont have curl when i try the same with curl instead of wget

Comment: i installed curl and it still doesnt work. what else options do i have?

Comment: What is the exact crontab entry you made?

Comment: I made 2 crontabs now with curl and wget. I don't know which works, but it works. It's somehow extremely delayed. But it works now. So i don't really care what/how. i simply did a 5 minute crontab of wget/curl ip:port/example.php